# Python and Strptime Difference When Variable Set or Read From File But Exact Same Value

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

Going for worlds worst title there but I can basically sum this weirdness up in one line.

This works fine:

```
dnow=datetime.datetime.now()
racetime = '2016-01-05 13:39:53.968000'
NewRaceTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(racetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
timedifference = dnow - NewRaceTime
```

But when racetime is read from a file in that exact same format it won't work.

If I remove the `racetime = '2016-01-05 13:39:53.968000'` things start going sideways.

If I use:

```
print racetime
```

It returns exactly the same `2016-01-05 13:39:53.968000.` I can't see any extra blank spaces or anything on the file or IDE. As far as I can see it is the exact same.

But even though there's no visible difference Python is finding something:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/PycharmProjects/Project/Script.py", line 153, in <module>
    NewRaceTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(racetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

There is no difference in me setting

```
racetime = '2016-01-05 13:39:53.968000'
```

And leaving it as racetime is already read from the file. Unconverted data remains said white space or something to me but there doesn't seem to be any.

To add to the weirdness I've used pretty much the exact same thing with XML and it's worked fine. Read in the time setting it as .text from the XML and Python was able to compare it to the current time without a problem.

I can't wrap my head around this. It seems daft there has to be something stupid I'm missing but I'm out of ideas here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a new line `\n` at the end of your file. You can strip it out like so:

```
import datetime

dnow = datetime.datetime.now()

with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    racetime = f.read()
racetime = racetime.rstrip()

NewRaceTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(racetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
timedifference = dnow - NewRaceTime

print racetime
```

Comment: Spot on! Coming from .net the way Python looks at things is a little different in places. Thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

A line ending such as '\r\n' might be the problem.